# Moving group in another hierarchy changed the group ID in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using Keycloak version 20.0.3. In the admin console, if I move a child group to the root level, the group ID changes and all the information inside the database belonging to the old group ID becomes zombies. Do we have any option to retain the group ID?

[image]